# Recommendations to learn about the use of toposes in logic?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, topos-theory

I'd like to learn about the use of toposes in logic. The "logic" side I know quite well, but of the "topos" side I am totally ignorant.

Which books/articles (formal and/or casual) would you recommend to start with ?

Is it usefull to learn first about Grothendieck toposes in order to contextualize the topic ?

Is it usefull to trace back to Lawere and Tierney's work in the 70's, or can I start directly with more recent accounts like Caramello and others ?

Comment: One development of topos theory which makes no attempt to show its connection to the algebraic-geometric side of it but instead is intended to relate to its uses in logic can be found in the classic Makkai and Reyes "First-order categorical logic". They start with Grothendieck toposes and gradually show their connection to logic. There is a texified version freely available. To complement, the two-volumes of Johnstone's "Sketches of an Elephant" are also good, and part D especially deals with some categorical logic.

Answer (score 19):

In no particular order:

- Mac Lane & Moerdijk, *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* (1992).  Clearly explains things like what a Grothendieck topology and a Lawvere-Tierney topology are, and gives some applications in logic like how to rephrase classical forcing in the language of topos or how to prove the consistency of Brouwer's theorem on the continuity of all real functions in intuitionistic logic.
- Lambek & Scott, *Introduction to Higher-Order Categorical Logic* (1986).  This one is more about the connection between the categorical and syntactic sides.
- Johnstone, *Topos Theory* (1977).  May be easier to digest than his monumental and more recent *Sketches of an Elephant*, which seems to be the standard reference for nearly everything, but which I personally find very difficult to navigate.
- Fourman & Scott, “Sheaves and Logic”, p. 302–401 in Fourman, Mulvey & Scott, *Applications of Sheaves (Durham 1977)*, Springer LNM **753** (1979).  The word “topos” isn't used, but this is about the applications to logic of sheaves on a locale (what would now be called a localic topos): although the terminology is not quite what has now become standard (e.g., they write “cHa” (complete Heyting algebra) for what would now be called a “frame”), I think this is still a very good course on the subject.  (Also check out Fourman & Hyland's “Sheaf Models for Analysis”, p. 280–301, in the same volume for plenty of examples.)
- van Oosten, *Realizability: An Introduction to its Categorical Side* (2008).  This is about the effective topos (or at least, realizability topoi) specifically, so maybe don't read it if you only care about Grothendieck toposes, but if you care about more general elementary topoi it has a lot of illuminating material about the internal logic and internal mathematics.
- If you care about algebraic geometry (and how to use the internal logic of a topos in algebraic geometry), then Blechschmidt's thesis [*Using the internal language of toposes in algebraic geometry*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.03685) is very much worth reading.

Comment: Additionally, part III of McLarty's _Elementary Categories, Elementary Toposes_ (1992). [Preview on Google Books](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=V8cON1x39bIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Minor correction: the article of Fourman & Scott is titled "*Sheaves and Logic*", not "*Sheaves in Logic*.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add *Handbook of Categorical Algebra: Volume 3, Sheaf Theory* by Francis Borceux. This builds on the previous three volumes which introduce all the category theory necessary. I found this to be the most clear and well-structured exposition of topoi and the categories of sheaves. In particular the discussion of the internal language of a topos and the section on the law of the excluded middle is excellent.

Answer (score 7):

1. Topoi: Categorical Analysis of Logic by Goldblatt

This book is an exceptional feat of pedagogy. It is very motivated, and more or less easy to follow. Sometimes, in my experience, there are bumps. For that, I think investigating more of logic/lattice theory would help.

2. Sheaf Theory by Daniel Rosiak (2022)

Modern book. It's main topic is not about toposes in logic but it is mentioned along the way. The book is very stimulating as it discusses the philosophical element of the matter. Some people would dismiss that as crankery, but I personally found value in it.

All of them will take a long while to finish cover to cover though. I've spent some months on both, and have not been able to properly go through half. But, I suppose the difficulty stems from my lack of experience. In my opinion, there are, what I'd consider, years worth of ideas in each.

Comment: Have to say one thing though, I am amazed these books were not mentioned already!

Comment: Thank you all for your kind suggestions. Is there a close link between toposes and the so called "categorical Galois theory" developped by Janelidze or are they quite disjoint matters ?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that both books are published open access: [Goldblatt](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/books-by-independent-authors/topoi-the-categorial-analysis-of-logic/toc/bia/1403013939), [Rosiak](https://doi.org/10.7551/mitpress/12581.001.0001).

Comment: [The best things in life are free](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeWF5tluHT4&ab_channel=RobertMorse-Topic)